# scheme - remainder for fraction

Tags: scheme

Is there any function in Scheme that support the operation "div" for **fraction**?

meaning - 11 div 2.75 = 4.

Comment: Your title says "remainder" but you don't seem to need that based on the body of the question.  Can you clarify that please?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - sorry bill. I mean that if I have 11 div 2.72, it also will give me result of 4, because (4*2.72) +  (0.12) =11. 0.12<4. In other word, I try to find a function in Scheme that will give me the number of times number_1 is contained in number_2 when (number_1 > number_2 it will give me 0) I think that in other Programming language this operation call "div", but Im not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is: no, but you can define it:

```
#lang racket

(define (div a b)
  (floor (/ a b)))

(div 11 2.72) ;; => 4.0
```

Comment: thank u, but it give me diffrent answers in the next case: (div 2 1) => 2, while (div 3.5 1.75) => 2.0. This is important, because I cant use eq? for comparing two answers. Thanks.

Comment: In racket, you can wrap a call to inexact->exact around the result if you want an exact number. Also, it is *not okay* to use eq? to compare numbers, according to the racket documentation. Use = instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about `/` ?

In MIT Scheme:

```
1 ]=> (/ 11 2.75)

;Value: 4.
```

In Racket:

```
> (/ 11 2.75)
4.0
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, My example is not so good. I mean that 11 div 2.75 =4, but also 11 div 2.72 = 4 (because 4*2.72=10.88 + mod (0.12)).